# TortoiseSvn authorization failed on commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

i have setup svn server using svnserve.exe and TortoiseSvn on my pc.

svnserve.conf is this

```
  [global]
  anon-access = none
  auth-access = write
  password-db = passwd
```

passwd file is this

```
 [users]
 me = 12345
 others = 12345
```

authz file is

```
[/]
* =
me = rw
others = rw
```

i can commit and read from svn, but other users only are able to read.
commit action gives authorization error.

we dont even see authorization dialog from TortoiseSvn.

i tried to delete userdata/auth directory. did not work.

anyone experienced a similar issue?

Comment: sorry i didnt think it uses authz file unless "authz-db = authz" is defined. added authz file to answer now.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't - didn't realise you posted *entire* svnserve.conf, sorry

Comment: All I can suggest is try running svnserve with `--log c:\svn.log`, and check the log file after a user fails to commit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after a clean install of svn and tortoisesvn,
these settings worked. tortoisesvn finally asked my me password

svnserve.conf file

```
[general]
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
```

passwd file

```
[users]
saejox=12345
```

Answer (score -1):

this not contain authentication   svnserve.conf file

```
[general]
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
```

passwd file

```
[users]
saejox=12345
```

you must some variable in authz file
like group, wich repository and which permission
like this in authz

```
[groups]
team = bob, bill
devteam = bob, barry, brett

[/]
@team = r
bob = rw

[/wowapp/trunk]
@team = r
@devteam = rw
brenda = rw
```

Comment: Using `authz` is optional.